# AutoMapper.Collection.EntityFramework System.InvalidOperationException child collection removes entities

Tags: entity-framework, exception, collections, automapper

When mapping a dto parent with a child collection to an entity framework model parent with child collection, changes and additions to the child collection work fine; when the model child contains an entity that isn't in the the dto collection, the context.SaveChanges throws a System.InvalidOperationException which seems to indicate that the child item has been removed from the model collection but not deleted.

I'm not sure if this is the expected result. Could someone let me know if this is supposed to work (should SaveChanges cause the missing dto children to be deleted from the DB and not throw an exception)?
Thanks.

Comment: You will need to provide a working example demonstrating the problem. Any child collection reference would need to be mapped with a cascade delete policy that is backed up by the DB Schema to automatically clean up orphans. EF won't automatically generate delete statements and may just attempt to null out FKs which violate the FK constraint in the DB.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.